# How can I convert a duration or a string to an integer in a queryset in Django views.py?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to calculate the time difference between two rows.  This duration then needs to be adjusted up to 1 if the total is 0, or if the total is over 15 minutes, adjusted to 0--I was going to put this corrected amount in strtime.  Unfortunately, my calculated times are not correct nor can I convert the extracted minutes to an integer in order to test if the duration is > 15 or < 1.  The only reason I converted to a string was to see if I could then convert to an integer--it didn't work.  I also tried to convert to a pandas dataframe in order to do the calculations, but I could not get it back into some format to display properly on the html page.

How can I do an accurate calculation between rows and how can I adjust from 0 to 1 or > 15 to 0?  I have tried many different versions--just not having much luck.  I normally work in javascript--this is my first Django project.  I have sanitized and shortened the data.  This page will fit into an existing Django setup.  Thank you in advance!  Code is below.

```
models.py
class testmodels(models.Model):
    primary_key_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
    transactionDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

views.py
    items = testmodels.objects.filter(transaction_type='Pick').order_by('transactionDate')).values()
    items2 = items.annotate(totaltime=Window(expression=Lead('transactionDate')) - F('transactionDate'))
    items3 = items2.annotate(dtime=ExtractMinute(ExpressionWrapper(F('totaltime'),output_field=DurationField())))
    items4 = items3.annotate(strtime=(ExpressionWrapper(F(str('dtime')),output_field=CharField())))
    context = { 'itemdetails':items4}
    return render(request, 'test.html',context=items4)

test.html
  {% for row in itemdetails.all %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ row.transactionDate }} </td>
    <td> {{ row.userName }} </td>
    <td> {{ row.totaltime }} </td>
    <td> {{ row.dtime }} </td>
    <td> {{ row.strtime }} </td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}

Data:
    Transaction Date            User    Total Time  dtime   strtime 
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:20 p.m.    Bob     0:00:28     0   0.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:20 p.m.    Bob     0:01:18     1   1.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:21 p.m.    Bob     0:00:41     0   0.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:22 p.m.    Bob     0:23:50     23  23.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:24 p.m.    Bob     -1 day, 23:55:59    -4  -4.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:25 p.m.    Bob     0:00:41     0   0.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:26 p.m.    Bob     0:00:04     0   0.0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:26 p.m.    Bob     4:41:16     41  41.0    
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:46 p.m.    Bob     0:00:10     0   0
    Jan. 11, 2019, 3:46 p.m.    Bob     0:00:52     0   0
```

Comment: If you want to use the pandas approach, you can call df.to_dict(orient='records').  This will convert you df to a list of dicts (the same format as a values queryset), and you can pass it in as context to the template and use it the same way you are used to in the template.  Do you need a Django ORM solution?

Comment: @ac2001 -  Thank you!  The orient='records' helped immensely.  Now still working on the actual functions...Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at the conditional expressions in the Django ORM here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/.  I'm a little confused on the exact rounding that you are going for, if you could help me understand I can try to help.

Comment: @ac2001 I was able to figure out the time calculations using a pandas dataframe.  Using np.ceil and a lambda function took care of the time issues I had.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Great.  I put a purely Django solution in there too, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to understand the exact rounding scheme that you want but I think this will give you the structure that you are looking for:

Created a custom function for absolute value.  This works for Postgres, you will have to ensure it works for you DB.

```
functions.py

from django.db.models import Func

class ABS(BaseFunc):
    function = "ABS"

views.py
items = (testmodels
         .objects
         .filter(transaction_type='Pick')
         .order_by('transactionDate')
         .annotate(current_dtime=F('transactionDate'))
         .annotate(previous_dtime=Window(expression=Lead('transactionDate')))
         .annotate(diff_dtime=F('current_dtime') - F('previous_dtime'))
         .annotate(diff_minute=ABS(ExtractMinute('diff_dtime', output_field=IntegerField())))
         .annotate(rounding_scheme=Case(When(diff_minute=0, then=Value(0)),
                                        When(diff_minute__lt=15, then=Value(1)),
                                        default=Value(0),
                                        output_field=IntegerField())))
```